# Facebook: Unable to post update status

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I have an intent that shares a link. When a user click on the button and choose a sharing method everything works fine except for Facebook: when confirming the post update a message pops up saying something like: "unable to post update status"...

This is the code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "A wild BeAR appears! (https://twitter.com/L3on7)");
myIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Where's the problem? 

EDIT: what's the reason for the downvote?! -.-'

Comment: nothing. The app calls succesfully the intent so the logcat is empty

Comment: Can you update your status manually, from the Facebook App?

Comment: yep... it works perfectly

Comment: Can you try to add `EXTRA_TEXT` as `"https://twitter.com/L3on7"`, please?

Comment: ok it works. Write an answer so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is not letting customize what will be written at the title of the post. You can only send a url with an intent to Facebook App.

If you really must provide a title for that post you can use [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/) or [Easy Facebook Android SDK](http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/)